# What is a good way to update a cache whenever a Mongoid model is saved?

Tags: ruby, mongoid

One approach would be to add an `after_save` callback to each model. But there are 7 models, so it would be better to put this functionality in one place.

Is there a better approach? Perhaps by re-opening the Mongoid::Document module?

Actually I don't think `after_save` would work by itself. Probably need to include `after_update` and `after_destroy` also...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical answer to this is [mongoid-observers](https://github.com/chamnap/mongoid-observers). An observer is a class that receives callbacks for instances of the observed class, and can execute things like cache clears and whatnot on them.

Using it is fairly straightforward - you simply define which models you want to observe, and then implement callbacks. For example:

```
class PostObserver < Mongoid::Observer
  observe :post, :gallery

  def after_update(record)
    clear_cache_for record
  end

  def after_destroy(record)
    clear_cache_for record
  end

  private

  def clear_cache_for(record)
    Rails.cache.clear record.cache_key
  end
end
```